# jQuery click event on parent, but finding the child (clicked) element

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom

let say I have a parent element which has so many nested child elements inside of itself:

```
<div id="p">
    <div id="c1">
        <div id="c2"></div>
        <div id="c3"></div>
    </div id="c4">
        <div id="c5"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've already bind a `click` event on the parent:

```
$('#p').bind('click', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Because the event is assigned to the parent element, I always see the parent id, however, I'm wondering if there is any possible way to find out which of this child elements has been clicked?

I also can't assign any event to the child elements or remove the event listener from parent div.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You need to pass event object to function to get the item that triggered the event, event.target will give you the source element.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rLJMh/)**

```
 $('#p').bind('click', function(event) {
    alert(event.target.id);
 });
```

or

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rLJMh/1/)**

```
$('#p').bind('click', function(event) {
    alert($(event.target).attr('id'));
});
```

**Edit**

The first method `event.target.id` is preferred over second `$(event.target).attr('id')` for performance, simplicity and readability.

Comment: thanks man, it works! :)  ... i should wait to accept your answer!

Comment: For the record, `$(event.target).attr('id')` is the much slower version of `event.target.id` - see http://bit.ly/jqsource and search for `Sizzle.attr = function`. jQuery (or rather, Sizzle) has to go through all that code to get you your id, where just using the DOM gets it for you directly.

Comment: useful for me. +1

Answer (score 7):

You can try the below code. Also try the jsfiddle too(demo).

```
$('#p').on('click', function(event) {
    alert(event.target.id);
});​
```

[**Try the demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tnpwb/)

The answer to your second question is you can assign event to the child and remove from it's parent. Check this out.

```
.stopPropagation();
```

Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any
parent handlers from being notified of the event. [Read more](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

if you want the specific event to be executed only and allow no other event to be fired you use code below

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation()
```

Keeps the rest of the handlers from being executed and prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree. [Read more](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/)

I hope this will solve your problem. If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If your elements have grandchildren, there is a better way to get just the child. Note the greater than sign.

```
$('.parent > .child').click(function() {
    // This will be the child even if grandchild is clicked
    console.log($(this));
});
```