# How to use onclick on a Class but only on certain elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is how my HTML code looks like, in the real code there are several blocks like this. When you click somewhere in this DIV toogleDescription(this) gets called. My problem is, I don't want something to happen when you click on one of the ANCHORS (a), so is it possible to define certain DIV in the Javascript that nothing will happen?

```
<div class="dokumente_table">
    <div class="dokumente_group onclick="toggleDescription(this)">
        <img class="dokumente_triangle" src="/_files/img/triangle_13.png">
        <div class="button_group">
            <a class="button">Content...</a>
            <a class="button">Content...</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dokumente_download_frame">
            <a class="dokumente_download">Content...></a>
        </div>
        <div class="dokumente_row">
            Content...
        </div>
        <div class="dokumente_row">
            Content...
        <div class="dokumente_extra_row">
            Content...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So this is the Javascript that gets called.

```
function toggleDescription(that) {
    if($(that).find('.dokumente_extra_row').is(':visible')) {    
        $(that).find('.dokumente_extra_row').slideUp(500);
        $(that).find('.dokumente_triangle').rotate({
            duration: 1000,
            angle: 90,
            animateTo: 0
        });
    }
    else {
        $(that).find('.dokumente_extra_row').slideDown(500);
        $(that).find('.dokumente_triangle').rotate({
            duration: 1000,
            angle: 0,
            animateTo: 90
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758547/jquery-click-event-on-parent-but-finding-the-child-clicked-element

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/0v8vbnp8/

Comment: bind an on('click', function(e){e.preventDefault()}) event to the anchor you don't want anything to happen on click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want `toggleDescription` to be executed on click of a specific anchor, you can prevent the propagation of click using `stopPropagation()` method of event object in the particular anchors's click event.

For example if you want to skip execution for the the following anchor

```
<a class="dokumente_download">Content...></a>
```

You can do

```
$(".dokumente_download").click(function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change this line as described below:

```
 <div class="dokumente_group onclick="toggleDescription(this,event)">
```

then your function must be:

```
function toggleDescription(that,event) {
    if(!$('a').is(event.target)){
        if($(that).find('.dokumente_extra_row').is(':visible')) {    
            $(that).find('.dokumente_extra_row').slideUp(500);
            $(that).find('.dokumente_triangle').rotate({
                duration: 1000,
                angle: 90,
                animateTo: 0
            });
        }
        else {
            $(that).find('.dokumente_extra_row').slideDown(500);
            $(that).find('.dokumente_triangle').rotate({
                duration: 1000,
                angle: 0,
                animateTo: 90
            });
        }
    }
}
```