# Like/dislike system

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a like/dislike system on my Ruby on Rails project. I'd like to write my code shortly and make the handler just in one function. So here's my js code:

```
$(function(){  

  $(".action").click(function(){
      var current_post_tr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
      var _this = this
      $.ajax({
      if url: 'http://localhost:3000/dashboard/' + $(current_post_tr).attr('data-post_id') +'/' ??
        type: 'PUT',
        success: function(data){
          //was disliked
          if (data.action==2){
            if (data.action==1){
              (".dislikeAction").text(data.post_dislikes);
            }
            $(".likeAction").text(data.post_likes);
          }
          if (data.action==4) {
            if (data.action==3){
              (".likeAction").text(data.post_dislikeslikes);
            }
          $(".dislikeAction").text(data.post_dislikes);
          }
        },
        error: function(data){
          alert(data.responseText);
          console.log(data); 
        }
    });
  });
});
```

my HTML code :

```
<tr data-post_id="<%= p.id %>">
 <td><b class="margin"><h4><%=p.text%></b></h4></td>
 <td>by <%= link_to User.find(p.user_id).username, profile_dashboard_path(p.user_id) %>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
 <td class="action"><span data-action="like" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up likeAction"><%= p.likes_count %></span>
 <span data-action="like" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down dislikeAction"><%= p.dislikes_count %></span>  </td>
```

My question: how do i know which element was clicked: the span tag with likeAction or with dislikeAction. When i get this tag, then i can write the url to the end according with the clicked tag.

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate function:

```
$(function(){
  function recordMood(el){
   var post_id = el.parent('tr').data('post_id');
   var mood = el.find('span').data('action');
   $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/dashboard/' + post_id +'/' + mood,
      type: 'PUT',
      success: function(data){
        if(data.action==2){
                if (data.action==1){
                  (".dislikeAction").text(data.post_dislikes);
                }
                $(".likeAction").text(data.post_likes);
              }
              if (data.action==4) {
                if (data.action==3){
                  (".likeAction").text(data.post_dislikeslikes);
                }
              $(".dislikeAction").text(data.post_dislikes);
              }
            },
            error: function(data){
              alert(data.responseText);
              console.log(data); 
            }
      })
      }

      $('.action').click(recordMood($(this)))

    });
```

EDIT: Not sure I wrote it completely correctly, but I hope you get the idea. You could even improve the `success` function the same way.

If both actions are doing the same thing then you should avoid using conditional statements and instead try and extract the function, so you keep your code dry and if you have to change it later, then you only have to do that in one place instead of two(as in both sides of the conditional)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is actually answered here

[jQuery click event on parent, but finding the child (clicked) element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758547/jquery-click-event-on-parent-but-finding-the-child-clicked-element)

```
$(".action").click(function(event){
  var span = event.target;
  if ($(span).hasClass('likeAction')) {
  } else {
  }
  ...

});
```

Another solution is to use click event on span elements:

```
$(".action span").click(function(){
  var actionTd = $(this).parent('.action');
  if ($(this).hasClass('likeAction'))
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks, it may work, but how can i save my url into a variable ? if ($(span).hasClass('likeAction')) {
        var $url = "http://localhost:3000/dashboard/' + $(current_post_tr).attr('data-post_id') +'/like'"
      } else {
        var $url = "http://localhost:3000/dashboard/' + $(current_post_tr).attr('data-post_id') +'/dislike'"
      }
      $.ajax({
        url: $url , it's not working, i think, the problem is in my initializing

Comment: In this line

`var $url = "localhost:3000/dashboard/'; + $(current_post_tr).attr('data-post_id') +'/like'"`

you are using single and double quotes wrong. Try this

`var $url = 'localhost:3000/dashboard/' + $(current_post_tr).attr('data-post_id') +'/like'`