# finding child div id which is clicked in a div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have code in html like

```
<div id="edit" ng-click="editFunction($event)">
  <span id="1">
    click1
  </span>
  <span id="2">
    click2
  </span>
  <span id="3">
    click3
  </span>
  <span id="4">
    click4
  </span>
  ....
</div>
```

in controller.js

```
myDIV.controller('control',function($scope){
 $scope.editFunction($event){
   alert($event.target.id);
}

});
```

When user clicks in the div tag he should click on any of the span tags. Using the code we are able to get the div id.
But actually I need to know which span is clicked. Means id="1" or 2 or 3 ...
Thank you.

Comment: Try using event.currentTarget instead of event.target

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/23107800/5462775

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery click event on parent, but finding the child (clicked) element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758547/jquery-click-event-on-parent-but-finding-the-child-clicked-element)

Comment: numbers for ids of html elements are illegal!

Answer (score 0):

you can use clickevent, this might work:

```
    <div id="edit" ng-click="editFunction($event)">
  <span id="1" class="click">
    click1
  </span>
  <span id="2" class="click">
    click2
  </span>
  <span id="3" class="click">
    click3
  </span>
  <span id="4" class="click">
    click4
  </span>
  ....
</div>

    $('.click').on('click', function(event) {
    alert($(event.target).attr('id'));
    });
```

Comment: Actually, we should not need to use events for child tags